# Connect flume sink to another sink

Tags: flume

Apologies for the newbie question, but I have a slightly quirky Flume question.

**Scenario**:

1. I have Sink A, which grabs data, performs filtering, then sends successful data to some HTTP service.
2. I now want to log all successfully processed data to Hive.

Is there a way in Flume to grab data in a sink, then put it back into Flume to be picked up by another sink?

Ideally, a would like to write a Sink B that writes this data to Hive.

Answer (score 0):

So answering my own question:

> Is there a way in Flume to grab data in a sink, then put it back into Flume to be picked up by another sink?

No - not from what I found.

> Ideally, a would like to write a Sink B that writes this data to Hive.

I ended up piping this data to a kafka topic, which was then read by a new Flume agent that I had to write.

Comment: See documentation on Consolidation and Multiplexing - http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#consolidation